# Starting Logstash, connecting it to kafka producer

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I have installed Elasticsearch and Logstash as a primary component.

1. Started the Kafka producer that creates records every 4 seconds
2. `systemctl status logstash`, says the logstash is running
3. From the bin folder of logstash, when I run the below command to listen to a topic, it gives an error bash: “localhost:9092”: Permission denied

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin$ logstash -e ‘input { kafka { bootstrap_servers => “localhost:9092” topics => “Customer_demo” } } filter { json { source => “message”} } output { elasticsearch { hosts => [“localhost:9200”] index => “customer-demo” } stdout {} }
```

Comment: Can you add `--debug` when you run Logstash and share the output you get in the logs?

Comment: check error log with ```tail -f  /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log ```

Comment: if you connect(jar)   file on the root folder ,logstash can't read it ...create /home/me as such directory

Comment: forward complete log

Comment: The plain logs are as below -

Answer (score 0):

THe producer is not running now, however, the plain logs are-
I will take a snapshot by getting the producer up.

```
[2021-02-03T15:57:25,387][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
[2021-02-03T15:57:25,387][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=786233676, epoch=9143) to node 0: {}.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
[2021-02-03T15:57:25,827][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Discovered group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[2021-02-03T16:38:01,572][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1455350722, epoch=2665) to node 0: {}.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
[2021-02-03T16:38:01,585][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
[2021-02-03T16:38:03,556][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Discovered group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[2021-02-03T16:38:03,560][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
[2021-02-03T16:38:03,664][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator][main][5f6aa7eb9c5d8e0614720d7b335f8771464d38e2be323dcdb318ca41dfd3e53a] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Discovered group coordinator tej-Vostro-3590:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
```